# I have developed an ontology - how do I proceed?

Tags: rdf, ontology, triplestore, dataformat

I have just created an ontology. Now what? How do I use my ontology to create data? Should the ontology be in the database, or should it not? Should I write a java program to add data according to the ontology, or is there a tool that can format data based on the ontology? Is there a number of choices here, and which are they?

Comment: Creating instance data based on an ontology means just to use the properties and classes that occur in your ontology. Nothing more, nothing less. In RDF this means, create RDF triples `(s,p,o)` or `(s,rdf:type,C)` with `p` and `C` being in your ontology (aka vocuabary). Done

Comment: OBDA, R2RML etc.